# PC as a MIDI controller with output to USB

Tags: usb, midi

Is there a program to output MIDI signals to USB? I installed vmpk but I am not sure if it is able to do this job. At this stage, I want to control stm32f4-discovery with Deskripator-v2.

Comment: This should be generally possible. [VMPK](http://vmpk.sourceforge.net/) can translate presses on the computer keyboard to MIDI, you could also use a [MIDI sequencer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_sequencer) to output ready music.

Comment: OK but how do I tell vmpk to output MIDI signals to USB? Thanks

Comment: When you connect a USB MIDI device (such as your Discovery with MIDI descriptors) to your PC, it should be automatically recognized. Which OS are you using? Is this actually what you want?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. I connected stm32f4-discovery with Deskripator-v2 flashed on it to my PC with Ubuntu, but I can't see any MIDI device.

Comment: lsusb -v does not show my midi device. Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: There is a software running an USB host on the stm32f407. It should detect midi device when it is plugged in to the USB port, but I am not sure how should it behave when the board is connected to PC.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your use case is not supported by [Dekrispator version 2](https://github.com/MrBlueXav/Dekrispator_v2). Quote from the project description (emphasis mine):

> Connect a **USB MIDI controller** (like Korg NanoKontrol...) to the board's micro USB connector and control the synth.

The [video linked in the project description](http://youtu.be/fcLrcDCaI7w) shows the MCU board connected with a MIDI controller via USB-A to Micro A adaptor.

[USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) is a [master-slave bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master/slave_(technology)) where *only one party* can be the master (USB host). The PC acts as the USB host normally. However, Dekrispator running on an [MCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) board seems to act as a USB host, too.

#### See also

- [What exactly are the differences between a USB host and device](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/49140/192094)

### Software (programming) solution

This application won’t work with a computer. You would have to set up the MCU application to act as a USB device (slave) to be able to connect it to the PC. This would be a pure programming task requiring an extension of the Dekrispator USB library to support the USB device mode (or replacement of the library).

### Hardware solution

You could work around this problem by extracting the MIDI signal from the MIDI/USB communication using a classical [MIDI connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI#Connectors). To do this, you’d need two USB-MIDI converters and one [5-pin DIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI#Connectors) female-female adaptor.

```
     USB             MIDI out            MIDI in              USB
PC <-----> USB-MIDI ----------> DIN F-F ---------> USB-MIDI <-----> MCU
```

Comment: Today I bought a cheap MIDI controller and tested that Deskripatorv2 works with it. I am now trying to figure out if it is possible for PC to act as USB device. I found this: http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/ and I am now trying to figure out if it is going to work.

Comment: I am sorry, I think it’s not possible with any x86 PC, maybe with an ARM-based computer (Raspberry PI, for example). From the page that you linked (emphases mine): _“Many Linux systems will not be able to use it, since they only have **PC-style USB Host (master) hardware** in a PC, workstation, or server. But when you're putting together **embedded Linux systems**, a USB peripheral controller option is routine; it's often integrated into processors.”_ However, you could take the synth part of Deskripator together with a USB device library and run that on your MCU.

Answer (score 0):

You can send MIDI via USB between two hosts with this device:
[MIDI USB-USB](https://compasflamenco.com/midi-c-3/midi-usbusb-p-4.html?language=en)